# jest - coverage report now showing all files

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am manually setting-up for jest.

My repo struture:

```
my-proj
 - src
  - components
   ...
   - accordion
    - index.jsx
  - tests
   - components
    - accordion.test.js
  - setupTests.js
 - package.json
```

When I run `npm run test-coverage` to get the test coverage, it only returns the files I've tested but not all files inside `/src`.

[image]

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "test-coverage": "jest --coverage", 
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: I only see just one test file `accordion.test.js`. What did you expect?

Answer (score 7):

I've just stumbled upon your question having the same problem as you do.
Try running `jest --coverage --watchAll`. That should cover all files coverage and show which aren't, even without test files.

Comment: Amazing, it was what was missing in my case. I didn't know that the coverage report only shows tested components by default. Seems counterintuitive for a coverage test...

Comment: Doesn't this also put jest in watch mode though?

Answer (score 2):

to get all files report, you have to pass `--collectCoverageFrom='app/**/*.js`'

where `app/` is your main folder, also, you can try to put all of these settings in your jest.config.js file

```
collectCoverageFrom: ['app/**/*.js'],
```

[jest config file - collect coverage](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#collectcoveragefrom-array)